# Float div element without jquery

Tags: javascript, html, css

How can i float a div element without using jquery? I need that because i want to float an element inside my websites's right sidebar.

I'm searching a pure css or javascript solution with no external libraries.

I want to clarify my question: i have (in example) 4 elements in my sidebar.

When user scrolls down the page and finds the last element, this element must be fixed and always visible. But if the user scrolls up and there're other elements in the sidebar, the square box is fixed no more.

Comment: css property float:right ?

Comment: There is no need to use Javascript (or Jquery).  This is strictly a CSS problem.  Use float:right, float:left, or float:none in your CSS to get the desired result.

Comment: The easiest answer is that "float" never had anything to do with jquery to begin with,  It's all CSS.

Comment: Someone didn't do their research... Here is a google search in which I simply typed in "float" https://www.google.ca/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=float&safe=off

Comment: The question has nothing to do with 'float' but rather fixed/absolute positioning.

Answer (score 0):

Sure - no JS needed.

```
div {
   float: left;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The `float` is a CSS property of an element and it has nothing to do with jQuery. You can float an element `left` or `right` or reset it using `none` by the below:

```
float: left;
float: right;
float: none;
```

So, if you have a `div` with class, `right-sidebar`, you can float it this way:

```
.right-sidebar {
    float: right;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the float attribute in css.

```
float: none|left|right|initial|inherit;
```

Answer (score 0):

Why do you need JavaScript or jQuery to float elements?
All you need to do is to add `{float:left or float : right}` 
to your element CSS property.